# Confirm if sub-query is selective?

Tags: trigger, soql, before-trigger

I have a query in a before-update trigger that looks like following:

```
[SELECT Id,(SELECT Id,Active_opp__c 
            FROM Opportunities 
            ORDER BY Days_from_Last_Stage__c ASC) 
 FROM Account WHERE Id IN: conAccMap.values()]
```

I have checked this in query plan and it looks like :

[image]

Is there a chance that the inner query will cause selective query error since I dont have a WHERE Clause on an indexed field in the inner query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relationship fields are always indexed, so the sub-query will use the Opportunity.AccountId index. The Query Plan window only shows the top-level plan choices, and of those, the one with the lowest cost is considered (the Index of Account.Id in this case). In other words, there's no chance that the child query would result in a selective query error.

Comment: Would the subquery cause a selectivity exception in the case of extreme data skew (>200,000 child records on a single account)?

Comment: @sfdcfox, the query in my question uses 'conAccMap.values()' where as when I was checking in the query plan, I hardcoded an account Id( I didn't want to post in forums). So in real time, in my trigger, is there a chance of hitting selective query limit due to large number of opportunities in my org(I believe its round 2 mil) or large number of Accounts(>1.5 mil)?

Comment: @DavidReed You'll run in to other problems before you could possibly run into a non-selective query error. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/156493) for more information.

Comment: @Krishna If you are querying by ID or lookup fields, there's no chance of that happening. All Id-type fields are indexed.

Comment: (For example, my primary org has a single Account with 244,000 Cases).

Comment: @DavidReed Your problem with that account is you can't delete it, and you risk row lock errors every time you create or edit a case on that account, and in Classic, it might take ages to load the cases, etc. The account should be essentially unusable by this point. You still shouldn't get a non-selective query error, though, until you get up towards the 333,333 limit.